# stacked graph with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

My data file looks like this

```
A 20120301 4
A 20120302 3
B 20120301 5
B 20120302 6
C 20120303 5
```

except there are many more than just A,B,C and I want to create a stacked graph with gnuplot (similar to the "Stacked histograms" from the [gnuplot demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html))

```
20120301 = (A:4 + B:5)
20120302 = (A:3 + B:6)
20120303 = (C:5)
```

So far I could not convince plot to read the data in that format. Do I have re-arrange the data file for this? Or is there a way for gnuplot to read the data in that format?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out which elements you want stacked from your description.  Is each row corresponding to a stack of boxes?  e.g. `B:5` is stacked on `A:4` in the 20120301 column?  If so, what is the significance of the letter (A,B,C).  Is that supposed to correspond to the color of the box?

Comment: @mgilson Yes, you got that right. A-C are types (and hence colors). In my example you should see 3 stacked columns with the total heights of 9, 9, 5. The first two columns should be made of two boxes that are A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've managed to beat it into a form that will work (you'll need at least gnuplot 4.3):

```
set boxwidth 0.75 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set datafile missing '-'
set style histogram rowstacked
set style data histograms
set yrange [0:]
plot for [i=2:4] 'test.dat' u i,'' u (0.0):xtic(1) notitle
```

and here's the datafile `test.dat`

```
#date     A B C
#missing data is marked by a minus sign
20120301  4 5 -   
20120302  3 6 -
20120303  - - 5
```

Phew!  I've never been much good with gnuplot when it comes to histograms.  Hopefully this will work for you (Sorry about the change to your datafile).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, @mgilson. With the column oriented approach I got it to work, too (before asking the question :) Not changing the data format is the whole point of the question.

Comment: @tcurdt -- Well then in that case, I would say not possible ;).  (but I would love to be proven wrong).